# How to avoid an existing datetime value from 'disappearing' upon clicking datetimepicker?

Tags: java, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker in the form for user to set the Start Date Time for setting an announcement. 
For existing data, I will populate the info into the form.

HTML code:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='divEditEndDateTime'>
<form:input id="editEnddatetime" path="editEnddatetime" type="text"
    class="form-control input-datetime" readonly="true" />
</div>
```

Javascript code (to initialize the datetimepicker):

```
$('#divEditStartDateTime').datetimepicker({
    format : 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
    ignoreReadonly : true,
    minDate : new Date()
}).on("dp.change", function(e) {

    // validate field again after date change
    $('#editStartdatetime').valid();

    //if there is value on end date then only validate 
    var endDate = $('#editEnddatetime').val();

    if(endDate !== null && endDate !== ''){
        $('#editEnddatetime').valid();
    }
});
```

Javascript code (to populate the info into the form):

```
$("#editStartdatetime").val("29/07/2019 17:33");
```

However, upon clicking the datetimepicker, the existing date 'disappear' (as shown in the picture).

[image: troubleshoot-datetimepicker]

This only happen for date that is before today's date. 
This won't happen for if the date is set as future date. (Eg. 01/01/2020 00:00)

I have tried different ways of setting the datetime value, such as
`$('#divEditStartDateTime').data("DateTimePicker").date("1/11/2016 12:23");` but I still got the same result.

Comment: The right way to set value on datetimepicker is using [`date`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#date). Your issue is that you are trying to set a value that is before [`minDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#minmaxdate).

Comment: @VincenzoC So `....data("DateTimePicker").date("...")` is the correct way? But I have to set a date before minDate for existing announcement. Do you have any advise on how to achieve this without the datetimepicker appear to be empty once the user interact with it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's preferred to use [`.data("DateTimePicker").date("...")`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#date) over jQuery `val()`. My suggestion is to remove `minDate` option and set it dinamically (and conditionally) after you have set the "existing announcement" value.